# Convert data from JSONB type to Array type in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with columns in `jsonb` format which contains data like this:

```js
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

I want to convert column to array column type but I don't know how to do it properly.
Example of my script structure:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "products" ADD COLUMN "test_array" VARCHAR(2)[];

UPDATE "products" SET test_array = do converting here;

ALTER TABLE "products" DROP COLUMN "test";
ALTER TABLE "products" RENAME COLUMN "test_array" TO "test";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax looks odd, but this works:

```
update products 
   set test_array = array(select jsonb_array_elements_text(test));
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/o05bREz0)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a helper function

```sql
create or replace function json_array_to_array(j jsonb)
returns text[] language sql immutable as
$$
  select array_agg(el) from jsonb_array_elements_text(j) el;
$$;
```

and then simply

```sql
alter table products alter column test type text[] using json_array_to_array(test);
```

The function may be useful in other cases too.